# The expression contained an invalid collating element name c++ regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a regex. I am finding the regex in a string. However every time I run (not compile it) I get this error: `The expression contained an invalid collating element name`. This is my regex:
`:\w*:{[\w\s-+=\/*^%!;\(\)\[\]\{\}]*}:funcEND:`.
When I use it in my program:
`regex const functionRegex(":\\w*:\\{[\\w\\s-+=\\/*^%!;\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]*\\}:funcEND:");`.
Can anyone tell me why this is raising an error? I looked online, but found nothing that I could use. I also checked the regex wiki.

Here is some text that should match:

```
:functionDetector:{
    foo=foo+bar;
}:funcEND:
```

and:

```
:foo:{
    // hello world
}:funcEND:
```

Here is some text that should NOT match:

```
^BANK^{
    foo=1;
    bar=5;
}^BANK^

^UPDATE^{
    CALL:functionDectector;
}^UPDATE^

:hello:{
    // goo
}:qwerty:
```

Source code:

```
regex const functionRegex(":\\w*:\\{[\\w\\s-+=\\/*^%!;\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]*\\}:funcEND:");
ptrdiff_t const matchCount(distance(sregex_iterator(content.begin(), content.end(), functionRegex), sregex_iterator()));
ostringstream extraFuncInfoOSS;
extraFuncInfoOSS << "Extra functions detected: " << matchCount << "...";
cout << extraFuncInfoOSS.str() << endl;
```

Comment: Possibly because you didn't post compilable code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know it was needed because it was a question about regex.

Comment: Its a question about the C++ regex implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Source has been added.

Comment: That is still not compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the dash `-`, or make it the first character right after the opening square bracket `[`. The dash has a special meaning withing square brackets.

Comment: Thank you! The site I was using did not mention that!